# Plot a graph of a DataFrame of Timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I got a `.csv`-file containing lists of time spans like this:

> 00:00:00.000580;00:00:00.000893;00:00:00.001355;00:00:00.001767;00:00:00.001973;00:00:00.002694;
>   00:00:00.000069;00:00:00.000689;00:00:00.000873;00:00:00.001097;00:00:00.001920;00:00:00.002563;
>   00:00:00.000812;00:00:00.001307;00:00:00.001701;00:00:00.002561;00:00:00.003196;00:00:00.003600;
>   00:00:00.000702;00:00:00.001229;00:00:00.001750;00:00:00.002014;00:00:00.002633;00:00:00.003152;
>   00:00:00.000776;00:00:00.001774;00:00:00.001989;00:00:00.002115;00:00:00.002504;00:00:00.003228;
>
> ...

I'd like to use a jupyter notebook and pandas to read in this file and print a simple graph of the data. This is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd

inputFile = "D:\\times.csv"

names = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fivth', 'Sixth'] 
usecols = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
data = pd.read_csv(inputFile, usecols=usecols, sep=';', header=None, names=names, parse_dates=True)

#data.head()
data.plot.bar()
```

Whenever I run my notbook, I get an error message

> TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

It seems the csv-file is imported correctly, since I can write out the content of my `DataFrame` using `data.head()` and it looks ok.

What do I need to do to plot a graph from my data?

**Edit:**

This is what I get from `data.info()`:

> RangeIndex: 200 entries, 0 to 199
>   Data columns (total 6 columns):
>   First     200 non-null object
>   Second    200 non-null object
>   Third     200 non-null object
>   Fourth    200 non-null object
>   Fivth     200 non-null object
>   Sixth     200 non-null object
>   dtypes: object(6)
>   memory usage: 9.5+ KB

Comment: What is data.info() telling you?

Comment: I added the `data.info()` output into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert all data [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then to [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) - integers, so can be plot. `Apply` is used because `to_timedelta` works only with `Series` (columns of `df`)

```
data = data.apply(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x).dt.total_seconds())

data.plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Oh, thanks for the quick response! This works! So it looks like `DataFrame.plot()` only works on "real" numerical values?

Comment: I think it looks no see - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8711